# mysms API login and get SMS

Tags: sms

I am developing a program to be able to send and get SMSs using **MySMS**.
I have the API Key and I managed to write a code for sending SMS.
But I have a problem when trying to login to the API and get SMSs. I am using Postman and it is giving me response code 500 when I try to login.

https://api.mysms.com/rest/user/login

Any clue on what I am doing wrong, all my data is correct but I am not sure about the format or any other thing?

[image: image explaining the parameters and documentation and the response code]

Answer (score 0):

```
       $url      = 'https://api.mysms.com/json/user/login';
      $mydata  = array(
                        'apiKey'   => $apikey,
                        'msisdn'   => $msisdn,
                        'password' => $password,
                        
                    );
    $post_data = json_encode($mydata);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
```

Comment: This code is working properly. I have tested

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).